# Pineapple or Date Palm?

Tags: identification, palm

I'm getting conflicting identification from various people. Does anybody know what the difference between a Pineapple and Date Palm is? Here are some palms that I have seen in my neighborhood each of which have been identified as both Pineapple and Date Palms.

[image: Palm Tree 1]

[image: Palm Tree 2]

[image: Palm Tree 3]

[image: Palm Tree 4]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The confusion is because of the use of common names - this palm is commonly known as either Pineapple Palm, or Date Palm, or Canary Date Palm - its proper name is Phoenix canariensis.

Comment: And they are all the same palm?

Comment: Also, how do you know that this is Phoenix Canariensis and not Phoenix dactylifera?

Comment: Yes, they're all the same palm to answer your first query. Secondly, P. dactylifera has a straight trunk in maturity, a straight but dumpy trunk when smaller, without the bulbous part below the crown, and produces edible dates.

Answer (score 4):

Pineapple palms typically refer to Phoenix canariensis and (typically) have a thick trimmed trunk with the overall appearance of a large pineapple.

The Date fruit come from the Phoenix Dactylifera. There are a number of varieties with the fruit of the Medjool variety being the most desirable and the Deglet Noor variety is very common.These are commonly used as "street trees" and may be seen throughout the Las Vegas Strip. When used as an ornamental tree, the tree is 'skinned' with a chain saw and a 'diamond' cut is accomplished.

Phoenix roebelenii is another "date" palm, commonly referred to as a Pigmy Date Palm.